# Is it possible to assign value to a precreated Paragraph in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, paragraph

Consider the following **XAML** code:

```
<RichTextBox Name="dataRichTextBox" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <FlowDocument Name="dataFlowDocument" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Paragraph Name="dataParagraph">

        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

What I would like to do is, directly assign a a `Paragraph`, created programmatically, to `dataParagraph` as defined in the **XAML**.

the code for that looks something like:

```
Paragraph paraOne = new Paragraph();
Run run1 = new Run("I am run one"+Environment.NewLine);
// run1.Background = Brushes.Green;
paraOne.Inlines.Add(run1);
dataParagraph = paraOne; // expect that it will show up on the RichTextBox.
```

I have tried it, and it doesn't work. The examples I read so far, all seem to create the `FlowDocument`, `Paragraph` Programmatically and then assign Runs' to them. Is it possible to achieve it the way I have implemented.

Comment: It appears that, If I only declare the RichTextBox and bind Document, Paragraph and Run Programatically, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace the paragraph declared in XAML with a new one, but you can work with it directly.

Keeping your XAML as-is, change your code to this, and it will work:

```
dataParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("I am run one" + Environment.NewLine));
```

Alternatively, just add the new paragraph to the `FlowDocument`, rather than trying to assign it to the existing paragraph.

Comment: I resorted to solving it the hard way, that is create the whole thing from scratch. But this is what I would be doing If I knew it before :). Perhaps, I can refactor my code later and use this technique.